AMD Radeon display UNCLAIMED Ubuntu 24.04
I'm stuck trying to get my radeon GPU to work since I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04
I understand that AMD has not released a proprietary driver for this version and i'm trying to get back to the existing opensource driver amdgpu.
Anyway I have always had issues with my laptop being hybrid graphics ( one intel integrated graphics card, and one amd radeon ).
I tried to find a solution on line and have tinkered here and there, but now i'm completely lost
Will someone help me ?
This "display UNCLAIMED" seems to me there is no driver at all but I can't figure it out
Thanks in advance
radikal_loulou@radikal-loulou:~$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] Mot de passe de radikal_loulou : 

  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:c0220000-c023ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0200000-c021ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1600,900
       resources: irq:29 memory:bfc00000-bfffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
radikal_loulou@radikal-loulou:~$ lspci -vnnk | grep -Ei -A12 "vga|3d|display" | grep -Ei "vga|3d|display|in use"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Kernel driver in use: i915
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])



This can be resolved temporarily by running modprobe amdgpu (if you have the driver loaded).
Walk through below
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:a000(size=256) memory:efc00000-efc3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: simpledrmdrmfb
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=640,480

Check if we have the amdgpu driver loaded in the kernal
lspci -k | grep amdgpu
Kernel modules: amdgpu

Then run modprobe
modprobe amdgpu 

and the device is hopefully claimed
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:104 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:a000(size=256) memory:efc00000-efc3ffff memory:c0000-dffff

Permanent Resolution: The problem seems to be the blacklist file
ls /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf

You can remove the file
rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf

